# Can anyone see the issue with my sql prepare statement?

Tags: ios, sqlite

Aloha everyone,

I am re-writing some of my apps, this time using storyboards and coding for iOS 7.  As such, I was interested in starting from scratch.  Basically, these are apps that pull words and their definitions from a SQLite database, present the words in a table view, then allow the user to tap on the word to see its definition in another view controller.  My problem is that while I can open the database, I never get past the sql prepare statement.  Here is the code:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Set up the database variable
    databaseName = @"MilSpeak.db";

    // Get the path to the documents directory and append the database
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    NSLog(@"databasePath returns: %@", databasePath);


    // Execute the "checkDatabaseStatus" method
    [self checkDatabaseStatus];


    // Query the database for all object records and construct the navyTerms array
    [self runDatabaseQuery];

}

    - (void)checkDatabaseStatus {
    // Create a File Manager object to check the status of the database
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath] == YES) {
        NSLog(@"Database exists");
    }
}

    - (void)runDatabaseQuery {
    // Set up the database object

    // Initialize the navyTerms array
    wordArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    definitionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Open the database from the device's filesystem
    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Opening the database for SQL pull");

        // Set up the SQL statement and compile if for faster access
        const char *sqlStatement = "select * from terms where usn = 'Y' or usn = 'y' order by word asc";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // Loop through the results and add them to wordArray and definitionArray
            NSLog(@"Stepping through the database rows");
            while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                // Read the database from the resulting row(s)
                NSString *aWord = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                NSString *aDefinition = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];

                // Populate the arrays with the values from the database pulls
                [wordArray addObject:aWord];
                NSLog(@"word: %@", aWord);
                [definitionArray addObject:aDefinition];
            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"There is a problem with the sqlite3_prepare_v2 statement.");
        }
        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

        // Count the contents of the database arrays
        NSLog(@"wordArray contains %lu items", (unsigned long)[wordArray count]);
        NSLog(@"definitionArray contains %lu items", (unsigned long)[definitionArray count]);
        allTerms = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:wordArray
                                               forKeys:definitionArray];
        NSLog(@"allTerms contains %lu items", (unsigned long)[allTerms count]);
    }

    // Close the database
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

I'm not sure what happened with the pasting of the code (the closing curly brace), but it's all there,  I know that the database exists and has entries - I used terminal to call up the contents of the terms table.

[image: showing terminal access to the database - 4714 entries]

The first number is an auto number, so I should be seeing 4,714 entries on my table view.  More importantly, if you look at the code for the runDatabaseQuery method, you'll that I tend to use a lot of log statements to check for certain conditions.  I put one as an else to the sql prepare if statement, and that's what's triggered.

[image: Logs from a sample run]

For some reason, my app doesn't like that statement.  If anyone can give me any assistance in dealing with this, I would be eternally grateful.  Thanks in advance for any responses.

After a suggestion from another user here, I put in a sql_error statement.  Here is the new runDatabaseQuery method:

```
- (void)runDatabaseQuery {
    // Set up the database object

    // Initialize the navyTerms array
    wordArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    definitionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Open the database from the device's filesystem
    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Opening the database for SQL pull");

        // Set up the SQL statement and compile if for faster access
        const char *sqlStatement = "select * from terms where usn = 'Y' or usn = 'y' order by word asc";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // Loop through the results and add them to wordArray and definitionArray
            NSLog(@"Stepping through the database rows");
            while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                // Read the database from the resulting row(s)
                NSString *aWord = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                NSString *aDefinition = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];

                // Populate the arrays with the values from the database pulls
                [wordArray addObject:aWord];
                NSLog(@"word: %@", aWord);
                [definitionArray addObject:aDefinition];
            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"There is a problem with the sqlite3_prepare_v2 statement.");
            NSLog(@"%s SQLITE_ERROR '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database), sqlite3_errcode(database));
        }
        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

        // Count the contents of the database arrays
        NSLog(@"wordArray contains %lu items", (unsigned long)[wordArray count]);
        NSLog(@"definitionArray contains %lu items", (unsigned long)[definitionArray count]);
        allTerms = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:wordArray
                                               forKeys:definitionArray];
        NSLog(@"allTerms contains %lu items", (unsigned long)[allTerms count]);
    }

    // Close the database
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

The resulting log statements made no sense.  There is only one table in this database, named terms, but apparently, my app can not recognize the table as such:

[image: log statements from sample run]

I used the terminal and got the following:

[image: terminal verification of terms table in database]

So I'm very confused as to what exactly is going on here.  Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

I followed @maddy's suggestion about changing the sql open statement as such:

```
if (sqlite3_open_v2([databasePath UTF8String], &database, SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
```

and still got the same result.  In the viewDidLoad and checkDatabaseStatus methods, I attempted to verify that the database was in the right spot, but maybe I didn't do that correctly.  I'm going to go back over the code again to see what I may have missed.

Comment: Log the error from the call to `sqlite3_prepare_v2` by calling `sqlite3_error`.

Comment: I used the following line immediately before the sqlite3_finalize command: NSLog(@"%s SQLITE_ERROR '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database), sqlite3_errcode(database));

Comment: I got this response: -[NavyViewController runDatabaseQuery] SQLITE_ERROR 'no such table: terms' (1).  This can not be the case, as the database only has one table, terms.

Comment: That means you are not opening the database you think you are. You should use `sqlite3_open_v2` and specify that you don't want to create a new database if it doesn't exist. Verify your database file is really in the Documents folder.

Comment: Thanks maddy.  I'll check on that sqlite3_open_v2 statement.  I have log statements to the effect that the database is where it is supposed to be and that it exists.  Thanks for the tip on the open statement.

Comment: Don't forget the filename is case sensitive on a real iOS device.

Comment: Here's the strange thing.  On my iMac at home (2009 model), I have exactly the same problem (I use an external drive to house the app files and just run Xcode on either my iMac or rMBP), but on my rMBP, everything once again works perfectly!  I don't know why it doesn't work on my iMac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what happened, but now it works.  I slightly tweaked the checkDatabaseStatus method, adding in a copy command to ensure that the database got in the right place.  That code is here:

```
    - (void)checkDatabaseStatus {
    // Create a File Manager object to check the status of the database
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    // Get the path to the database in the application package
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePathFromApp] == YES) {
        NSLog(@"Database exists");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Dude, where's my database?");
    }

    // Copy in the database from the application package
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp
                         toPath:databasePath
                          error:nil];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath] == YES) {
        NSLog(@"Database exists");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Dude, again, where's my database?");
    }
}
```

Thanks again Maddy.  Your question as to the location of the database is probably what did it, but now it runs perfectly! (at least thus far :D)  I just now have to figure out what I want to do with all the data.